# store data in Session using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS by creating a small application.

I am storing user information in sessionStorage at the time of successful login.

### LoginController.JS

```
app.controller("LoginCntrl", function ($scope, $location, angularService) {

    $scope.Login = function () {
        var UserName = $scope.UserName;
        var Password = $scope.Password;

        var getData = angularService.LoginInformation(UserName,Password);
        getData.then(function (msg) {
            if (msg.data == '') {
                alert('no data');
            } else {
                sessionStorage.UserName = msg.dataUserName;
                $location.path('/members');
            }

        }, function (error) {
            alert('error in Login');
        });
    };
});
```

On successful login, I am redirecting the user to '/memberList' and in 
memberlistCntrl controller I am checking if sessionStorage is empty or not. If it is empty then I assume that user is trying to access the site without login and I am sending the user back to Login screen

### Code in memberlistCntrl

```
app.controller("memberlistCntrl", function ($scope, $location, allMembers) {

    if (sessionStorage.length == 0)
    {
        $location.path('/login');
        return;
    }

    $scope.MembersList = allMembers.data;

    $scope.createmember = function (path) {
        $location.path(path);
    };
});
```

My questions,

1. Is it a right way to check if user is logged in or not?
2. Is sessionStorage the right object to store the data in "Session" so that i can access it through out all my pages or site?
3. Is there any better way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My questions,
>
> - Is it a right way to check if user is logged in or not?
> - Is sessionStorage the right object to store the data in "Session" so that
>     i can access it through out all my pages or site?

Well, it depends on your use-case. `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. *Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated.*

So, if you want your user to logout on opening another `tab`, you can continue using sessionStorgae. However, thats not the case in most of the sites(do you get logout from stackoverflow on opening a question in 'another tab' ?).

> - Is there any <strike>better</strike> other way to accomplish the same?

Yes. You can use **localStorage** or **cookies**. Stackoverflow keeps this information in a cookie named `usr`.

If you use chrome, open console(F12).

Go to Resources > Cookies and delete `usr`. Refresh the page and you'd be logged out.

Gmail, facebook uses a similar technique.

Now AngularJS provides [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) service to get/set or remove cookies.

The reason why `cookies` are preferred over `localStorage` objects to track login status is: cookies are passed to server with each request/response cycle and hence available at server side. If you dont get the required cookie for a  particular request, you can simply throw a status 401(Unauthorized) message.

Comment: how to disbale the session in another tab of browser?

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports $cookieStore to store your values.
please refer below **example**.

```
angular.module('cookieStoreExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookieStore', function($cookieStore) {
  // Put cookie
  $cookieStore.put('myFavorite','oatmeal');
  // Get cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookieStore.get('myFavorite');
  // Removing a cookie
  $cookieStore.remove('myFavorite');
}]);
```

Refrence :  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore

## OR - EDIT:

If you want to use sessionStorage for data-storage, Than you need to use $window.sessionStorage.
Let me suggest you one example.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="addItem('111')">Add item in session</a>

$scope.addItem = function(item){
    $window.sessionStorage.setItem(id,item);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will definitely look into $cookieStore. Am I doing the right thing by using sessionStorage or its just a mess? Is my approach valid?

Comment: sessionStorage is used in '$window' param. So use like $window.sessionStorage.setItem(id, 'Value');

Comment: how to retrieve that session value

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't want to violate DRY principle and copy and paste code that checks authentication in each controller

```
if (sessionStorage.length == 0)
{
    $location.path('/login');
    return;
}
```

Instead try to use `$routeChangeStart` in one place to prevent user going to page if he is not authenticated.

Example of how to achieve this: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/urls-routing-and-partials/listening-on-route-changes-to-implement-a-login-mechanism.html